# Iterating over all class properties

Tags: c#, reflection

Maybe quite a simple question but I have an initialized class object that is passed via parameter to another class. The class object is then read to check the values of its members and possibly alter them if incorrect.

I can access individual properties and change their values but what i want to do is loop through all the integer type properties to check their base value and alter it where necessary.

Here is an example of the object structure:

```
+ Prices
++ MainPrices
+++ RelevantPrices
++++ (Int) Price

+ SubPrices
++ MainPrices
+++ RelevantPrices
++++ (Int) Price

+Rooms
++ Data
+++ (String) Name
+++ (Int) NameType
+++ (String) Location
+++ (Int) RoomNumber
```

What I need to do here is get Rooms.Data and loop over all its Int type parameters. I've tried using reflection but for that I require a new instance reference for the type, all i have is the initialized class object here.

Can anyone advise what might be the best way to loop over and conditionally change their existing values please?

EDIT:

Heres some example code:

```
public class Test()
{

public Void Init(MyClassObject Data)
{

//Data is initialised with data, it has the structure explained in the original description

//What i need to do is loop over the initialised objects properties here in this Init method,
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'i require a new instance reference for the type"?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a new instance reference" vs "the initialized class object". A [mcve] would really help...

Comment: "but for that I require a new instance reference for the type" -- No, you don't need a new reference. Use the reference you already have, the one with the "existing values".

Comment: If you're having trouble with your reflection code, please share the code you are having trouble with, and say exactly *where* the problem is and exactly *what* the problem is. "It throws a null reference exception on the line where I call `SetValue()` is exact". "it dosnt work" isn't exact.

Comment: Updated the description, hopefully it makes things a little clearer. What i don't have here is MyClassObject object = new MyClassObject(); so without the 'object' I'm not sure how to use reflection to loop over the parameters...or maybe I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: You have the object. It's in the parameter called `Data`, so use `Data.GetType().GetProperties()` to get the properties of the object and start looping over them.

Comment: Thanks Craig, figured that but where i have the problem is the object isn't 'one level' it has a deep structure with properties under other types (i hope that makes sense), how do i access the properties of another type in this object 'type'?

Comment: You can loop the properties of the object and use something like objectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(objectInstance,null);

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of integer properties

```
var integers = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int)).ToList();
```